# Facebook SSL for apps

Tags: facebook, ssl, facebook-javascript-sdk

Facebook require a secure page for Apps.

Is there any way to get round this for development mode? Reason being is that our live server as an SSL but the development one doesnt'

Answer (score 0):

I've done that by using sandbox mode and disabling secure browsing for your FB account. Try it out. I've filled only the "Canvas URL" input. Left "Secure Canvas URL" blank.

Comment: Backticks ` are used for inline code formatting on StackOverflow, which is why your post looks strange. If you change them to apostrophes ' this will be fixed. It's too small and edit for me to fix myself.